# when client disconnects my tcp/ip litsener goes insane /how to improve or fix it

Tags: c#, sockets, console-application

Hello i have a tcp/ip listener which works perfect up untill the client disconnects or sends a string again i have no idea how to fix this

```
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(****);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
        TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
        int requestCount = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                //SQL SECTION OF CODE
                MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(*******);

                conn.Open();


                //TCP LISTENING SECtion of code
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[100025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                //char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '<', '>', ':', '\t' };
                //string[] FinalData = dataFromClient.Split(delimiterChars);
                //var DataLines = XDocument.Load(dataFromClient)

                ////PARSING THE XML STRING
                //var dataLines = XDocument.Parse(dataFromClient)
                //    .Descendants("DataLine")
                //    .Select(n => new
                //    {
                //        Amount = n.Element("Amount").Value,
                //        TellNo = n.Element("TellNo").Value
                //    });
                //foreach (var item in dataLines)
                //{
                //    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("StringlistenerUpdate", conn);
                //    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CustomerBalance", item.Amount));
                //    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CustomerAccountID", item.TellNo));
                //    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //    conn.Close();
                //    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Amount, item.TellNo);
                //}


                var Voicelines = XDocument.Parse(dataFromClient)
                 .Descendants("VoiceLine")
                 .Select(n => new
                 {
                     Amount = n.Element("Amount").Value,
                     TellNo = n.Element("TellNo").Value

                 });



                foreach (var item in Voicelines)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("StringlistenerUpdate", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CustomerBalance", item.Amount));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CustomerAccountID", item.TellNo));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Amount, item.TellNo);
                }

                ///  Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client : " + DataLines);


                string serverResponse = "Last Message from client :" + dataFromClient;
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);



                clientSocket.Close();
                serverSocket.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (OverflowException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Suppressed exception: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated on how to fix this(with explanation why and how ) and improve it if this question is not acceptable or more information is required please let me know i have debugged it no problems occur except when the client disconnects and re-sends (  but in general  i find this to be a very primitive tcp/ip listener

thank you

Comment: Well, the line with the `accept`-function has to be inside the `while`-loop to connect to another client after an exception.

Comment: Any time you `Read` from a network stream but don't check the return value, you've got a bug. As little as *one* byte might have been populated in your buffer. `Read` lines on one end do *not*, generally, match up in one-one correspondence with `Write` lines at the other end.

Comment: thanks you for the tips ill update it any other ideas will be appreciate to make the program less primitive

Comment: any ideas on how to make it able so that a client can connect repeatedly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of `Read`, don't use `ReceiveBufferSize` because it does not do what you think it does.

Don't stop the server socket after having processed a single connection. The server socket is responsible for listening. It is never connected.